# How can I display count of an entity in a mysql table column in the label text using eval()

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="eitems" runat="server" Text='<% Eval("total")%>'/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

//Here 'total' is a variable in the cs code used as

```
public void count()
{
    string query = "select COUNT(eid) from eventgallery where id='" + ddevents.SelectedValue + "'";
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        dr.Read();
        total = Convert.ToInt32(dr);
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

// its is displaying "total" instead of the value that I assigned to 'total'.

**IS THERE A WAY TO MAKE THE TEXT OF THE LABEL, THE COUNT **

Comment: your `Label` is inside a data control like a `Repeater` or `Gridview` - is the result of `count` for every item / row the same?

Comment: use `Text='<%# Eval("YourFieldName") %>'`, make sure its case sensitive

Comment: it didn't work as if i use fieldname it shows its value only and not the number of times that value present in that column

Answer (score 0):

use `Text='<%# Eval("YourFieldName") %>'`, You are missing `#`.

Comment: In the 'eid' column, i have same values and i want to show no. of time that value in that column. Label is in the gridview

Comment: I didn't get the solution yet, anyone can suggest some method on the above query.